# Avoiding redundant expressions in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way to avoid repeating column expressions in the SELECT query? I want to divide the sum and count of a column but would like to use the assigned name instead of repeating `SUM(value)/COUNT(value)` or using a sub query. Is this possible? If so, does that speed up the query by not repeating the calculation of the sum and count or does mysql remember already calculated expressions?

```
SELECT datalist.type, SUM(value) AS type_sum, COUNT(value) AS type_count, type_sum/type_count
FROM (...) AS datalist
GROUP BY datalist.type
```

throws: #1054 - Unknown column 'type_sum' in field list

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done, the alias `type_sum` will be recognized in other parts of the query such as `ORDER BY` but not among the selected fields where it is being declared. The next best thing here is to just use shorter names to alias the tables, you could just use letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you put it in outer query, this is the only way.

```
SELECT datalist.type, SUM(value) AS type_sum, COUNT(value) AS type_count, SUM(value)/COUNT(value)
FROM (...) AS datalist
GROUP BY datalist.type
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to use a alias table with pre-defined calculations and then later call it from outer table such as:

```
select d.type_sum/d.type_count as dividedValue from (SELECT datalist.type, SUM(value)
AS type_sum, COUNT(value) AS type_count
FROM (...) )AS d
GROUP BY d.type
```